# Type'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

**I have difficulty in writing code, an error in the protocol, I use xcode 7.3.1**
[image]

```
//2 Method dari protokol UITableViewDataSource->method 1.
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    //Return the numberofRowsInSection.
    return namaRestoran.count
}
//Method 2.
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndextPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    //Configurasi the Cell.
    cell.textLabel?.text = namaRestoran[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: You need to look at the entire error message; it should tell you which methods you didn't implement to conform to this protocol.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have spelled `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndextPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` incorrectly.

It should be `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the function:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return 1; // Or any other number
}
```

Comment: This one is optional.